# How to link Leads (emails) to Marketing emails sent in Odoo v8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have Leads and all my leads have emails set. Now I have sent emails to leads with "Mass Mailings" from "Marketing". But now when I click on my lead I do not see any link between the Lead (email) to emails I have sent with "Mass Mailings".

Is there a way to make a link between Lead (email) to email I have sent?

Comment: Which version you are using.? I think in V8 there is a fields between leads and Marketing Campaign See in any Lead > Extra Info (tab) > Marketting

Comment: Yes, there is a field there but if I send emails from "Marketing" by selecting the Leads (emails) there is not any traces that I ever send a email to that Lead. Is there a way to link automatically Leads and "Maketing" ?

Comment: You can create a new module for that, but just for now you can manually put entry.

Comment: Can you please give me a example of how creating that kind of module?

Comment: You can view various modeuls on apps.odoo.com

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of a module that can do this kind of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information about sent emails is available trough the model `mail.mail.statistics`. In this model you have everything you need. The following fields may be of interest for your task:

- `model` - as emails may be related to any Odoo model, this field tells you to which model was related the email. You are interested in records with `crm.lead` in this field
- `res_id` - the id of the corresponding model instance. In your case this fields links you to the `id` of your lead.
- `mail_mail_id_int` - the `id` of the objects of type `email.email` - the emails themselves

etc.

You can use this to create a list of emails related to a lead and show them in the crm lead form.

To do that, create a new Odoo module, extend the `crm.lead` object adding a One2many relation to the `mail.mail.statistics` model and extend the crm.lead view to show this new field.

For instance, in a file called `models/lead.py` in this new module, put the following:

```
from openerp import models, fields


class crm_lead(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    emails = fields.One2many(comodel_name='mail.mail.statistics',
                             inverse_name='res_id',
                             domain=[('model', '=', 'crm.lead')])

crm_lead()
```

Respectively, to extend the view, create a file `views/lead_view.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="mail_crm_stats.crm_lead_form">
            <field name="name">mail_crm_stats.crm_lead.form</field>
            <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Extra Info']"
                       position="after">
                    <page string="Emails sent">
                        <group name="emails">
                            <div>
                                <field name="emails" nolabel="1"
                                       class="oe_inline"/>
                            </div>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Now you should see additional tab 'EMails sent' in your lead form. Of course, this is just and example and the module may be improved to show better information about the sent emails. As the case is interesting I may commit soon a new version in the [github repository](https://github.com/andreiboyanov/odoo-mails_crm_stats) I created for the purpose..

You can download the entire module and test it from my github repository like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/andreiboyanov/odoo-mails_crm_stats mails_crm_stats
```

Answer (score 0):

In V8 there is a fields between leads and Marketing Campaign See in any Lead > Extra Info (tab) > Marketing, You can manually add your campaign to that, but if you need to automatically sync then you need to create a new module for that, but just for now you can manually put entry.You can view various modules on [here](http://apps.odoo.com).

Comment: This is not an answer to my question! I have asked if there exists a way of linking automatically "Mass Mailings" with Leads (email). Logically when I send 200 emails by day I cannot open each Lead and make it manually so I need this link do be made automatically when I send the email from "Mass Mailings". So please give me an example how to do it automatically.

Comment: I think the answer of your question is -> "You need to develop" thats it.

Comment: It would be nice from your part as guru to give me an example, as I have not worked in Python before.

Comment: okay on that note, I think this would help you https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/crm_task/ or else Lead-to-quotation module will also help you